# Sum of NSMutableData bytes

Tags: objective-c

I would like to have a sum of NSMutableData bytes, is this possible with a quick method, or I should implement my own?

I have NSMutableData `<4b01000F 00000005>` and I would like to know sum of all bytes (4b + 01 + 00 + 0F + etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in function. Sounds like you're trying to build some sort of checksum. You'll have to iterate through the bytes and start adding.

You might find this useful however: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1509152?threadID=1509152&tstart=96

Comment: Sad. Thank you for your answer. I'll think of something :)